# A word for too little of an adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I don't know if this juice is too sugary or too [little] sugary.

What word should I use to convey this meaning? I could use an antonym of the word:

> I don't know if this juice is too sugary or too unsugary.

But in this case "unsugary" is just a made-up word since there is *no good antonym* and this sentence isn't as good as the first sentence.

A third option, which still isn't as good as the first sentence, is:

> I don't know if this juice has too much sugar or too little.

Answer (score 6):

You want the phrasing "not [adjective] enough."

> I don't know if this juice is too sugary or not sugary enough.

Alternatively, you can use the antonym of your desired adjective.

> I don't know if this juice is too sugary or too [bland/dilute/flavorless].